# Combine all elements of two arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, and want to combine the ith elements in each one together:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
b = np.array(['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

I want to return

```
array(['ax', 'by', 'cz'])
```

What is the function for this?   Thx,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> b = np.array(['x', 'y', 'z'])
>>> c = np.array([i+j for i, j in zip(a, b)])
>>> c
array(['ax', 'by', 'cz'],
      dtype='|S2')
```

@DSM makes the point that if `a` and `b` had `dtype=object` you could simply add the two arrays together:

```
>>> a = np.array(["a", "b", "c"], dtype=object)
>>> b = np.array(["x", "y", "z"], dtype=object)
>>> c = a + b
>>> c
array([ax, by, cz], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was simple, just couldn't nail it down.

Comment: @mike no problem, when combining iterables it's almost always worth trying `zip`.

Comment: If `a` and `b` had `dtype=object`, then `a+b` would Just Work(tm).  [Actually, I think either one would suffice.]